# Inline Errors Inline with Terms & conditions @ WooCommerce Checkout

Tags: php, woocommerce

I'm trying do the following:
In checkout, if the T&C checkbox is unchecked I want to display an error notice inline next to the checkbox, as opposed to at the top of the page.

I've looked at this:
[Print Required Field Errors Inline @ WooCommerce Checkout](https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-display-required-field-errors-inline-checkout/)

But it seams the code will only work for form fields and not checkboxes. How do I approach this?

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to do the same thing, but unfortunately it's not possible to filter the T&C's checkbox input.

In the end I copied the `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/checkout/terms.php` to my theme `wp-content/themes/my-theme/woocommerce/checkout/terms.php` and inserted the inline error message there.